# vba: How to For Each Loop with Mutiple If, Else Conditions and Formulas based on dynamic criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro that calculates Values in a Range depending on their existence. If all exist then perform a certain calculation else it goes through a variations of multiple conditions and calculates according to what exist. I am so far able to get it to calculate if all values exist but not the variations of some not existing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. (see code below)

```vb
Private Sub example()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim s As Range
    Dim lastcol as Long
    Dim lastrow as Long
    Dim h1 As Variant
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim d As String
    Dim e As String

    lastcol = ws.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next

    h1 = ws.Range("A4:Z4").Find("Header1").Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False)
    'h2 to h6 - same as above

    a = "Header1"
    b = "Header2"
    c = "Header3"
    d = "Header4"
    e = "Header5"

    ws.Range(Range("A4:Z4").Find("Header0").Offset(0, 1), Range("A4:Z4").Find("Header6").Offset(0, -1)).Select
    With Selection
    For Each s In Selection

            'Calc (Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5) - ALL
    If s.Value.a = True And s.Value.b = True And s.Value.c = True And s.Value.d = True And s.Value.e = True Then
    ws.Range(Range("A4:Z4").Find("Result %").Offset(1, 0), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Formula = _
"=IFERROR(SUM(" & h1 & "," & h2 & "," & h3 & "," & h4 & ", If(" & h5 & "/" & h6 & ">1%," & h6 & "*1%," & h5 & "))/ " & h6 & ", """") "

        'Calc (Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4) - NO Header5
    ElseIf s.Value.a = True And s.Value.b = True And s.Value.c = True And s.Value.d = True And s.Value.e = False Then
    ws.Range(Range("A4:Z4").Find("Result %").Offset(1, 0), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Formula = _
"=IFERROR(SUM(" & h1 & "," & h2 & "," & h3 & "," & h4 & ")/" & h6 & ", """") "

        'Calc (Header1, Header2, Header3, Header5) - NO Header4
    ElseIf s.Value.a = True And s.Value.b = True And s.Value.c = True And s.Value.d = False And s.Value.e = True Then
    ws.Range(Range("A4:Z4").Find("Result %").Offset(1, 0), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Formula = _
"=IFERROR(SUM(" & h1 & "," & h2 & "," & h3 & ", IF(" & h5 & "/" & h6 & ">1%," & h6 & "*1%," & h5 & "))/" & h6 & ", """") "
    ' Total of 15 conditions and formulas

    End If
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your code (you have lots of undeclared variables), ditch `On Error Resume Next` as you are suppressing most problems, and therefore unable to check what's actually working. `s.Value.a` (and others similar to it) are not a valid code... you should review those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulas are pretty complex. I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you need correctly, but I wrote and tested this code. It should at least give you some ideas of what you can do to make your macro work.

```
Sub CreateDynamicFormula()

    Dim strList(1 To 5) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim counter As Long

    Const h1 As String = "Header1"
    Const h2 As String = "Header2"

    counter = 1

    'This is the inner loop
    'finds which columns meet your condition and adds them to an array
    For Each r In Range("A1:C3")
        If r.Value = h1 Then
            strList(counter) = r.Address
            counter = counter + 1
        ElseIf r.Value = h2 Then
            strList(counter) = r.Address
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next r

'Make Formula

    Formula = "=IFERROR(SUM("

    For Each s In strList
        'only returns array items that have text in them
        If Not s = "" Then
            Formula = Formula & s & ", "
        End If
    Next s

    Formula = Formula + ")"

    Debug.Print Formula


End Sub
```

Here is the spreadsheet I made to test the code: 
[image: Here is the spreadsheet I made to test the code]

Results: 
[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks a lot, You gave me a head start with adding the values if exist to an array. Now I just have to work on modifying the code to work with those complex formulas. Thumbs up!

Comment: Worked Perfectly. All I had to do to add my formulas was change the "If Not s = "" Then to "If s = "Header1" Then Formula = Formula (whatever I want). I just kept adding  "If s = "Header#" Then Formula = Formula (whatever I want) statements till I got my formula how I needed. Thumbs up.